# Prototyping a part with 2mm spacing on 0.1" matrix board?

Tags: prototyping, pins, spacing, breadboard

I have an Airwave [AWM682RX](http://www.active-robots.co.uk/airwave-58ghz-wireless-rf-av-receiver-module-p-1263.html) 5.8GHz video received and matching AWM683TX transmitter module. Oddly, one has pins spaced at 0.1", the other at 2mm.

So, **what's the best way to make a part with 2mm spaced pins fit on 0.1" matrix board?**

Answer (score 7):

The best way would be the adapter.

A quick way would be to take a dremel tool to the 
Vector board and route a slot. Epoxy the 2mm sockets to the
board and then run jumper wires to Vector K24A pins.

If you do not have many pins you could take a wire-wrap header
with 0.1" centers and bend the leads on one end to 2mm centers.
Solder the socket to bent leads.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to avoid soldering and just want to connect some devices up quick to breadboard, try this: [2.54mm to 2mm jumper wire](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/4-pin-254mm-to-20mm-female-jumper-wire-100mm-p-403.html)

Answer (score 4):

I make my own PCBs at home, so I'd just make a little adapter.